# How to visualise the following dataset?

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have the following dataset, reproducible in the statistical programming language R:

```
library(data.table)
sheet1 <- data.table(userID = c('abc123', 'abc123', 'abc123', 'def456', 'def456'), 
           sessionID = c('1529665492722.251rq8', 
                         '1529922427795.g2k607go',
                         '1529931067235.0yw5eqfa6', 
                         '1529945600035.345m7ym1', 
                         '1529950171742.fhmkcj6l'),
           month = '6',
           totalpageviews = c('10', '15', '56', '23', '24'),
           pagePath = c('application/123', 'application/456', 'application/789', 'application/101112', 'application/131415'))

sheet2 <- data.table(userID = c('abc123', 'abc123'),
                     sessionID = c('1529665492722.251rq8', '1529922427795.g2k607go'),
                     eventCategory = c('x', 'x', 'c'),
                     eventAction = c('y', 'z', 'a'),
                     pagePath = c('application/123', 'application/123', 'application/123'))
```

sheet1 and sheet2 have fields in common, namely userID and sessionID. I want to present the data to a colleague who does not have experience with spreadsheets. How can I visualise the data in a way that an untrained eye can extract insights?

I am open to explore different options. It can be R, excel or a BI tool like Power BI.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to visualize data, but what's the primary goal of the visualization? What are you trying to show to the untrained person?

Comment: All the activities that happened during a session. At session `1529665492722.251rq8`, 10 page-views were recorded of the page application/123 at which the user triggered 2 events x and c.

Answer (score 1):

It takes a bit of time to learn but ggplot2 can give you a lot of mileage. Check out http://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html

It may also help to convert your sessionIDs into something ordered or numeric in order to see a time series trend if you prefer that to the categorical variables you're currently using.

Here's how I might visualize what you presently have:

```
# install.packages('dplyr')
library(dplyr)
sheet <- full_join(sheet1, sheet2)

# install.packages('ggplot2') # visualization package
library(ggplot2)
# all data; bars including NAs and Event category/action
(p <- ggplot(sheet) +
  geom_col(aes(sessionID, totalpageviews, fill = interaction(eventCategory, eventAction)), position = 'dodge') +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = 'Event Category.Action')) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -30, hjust = .3)))

# just application/123
(p2 <- p %+% (sheet %>% filter(pagePath == 'application/123')))

# just page views and page path
(p3 <- ggplot(sheet %>% select(totalpageviews, pagePath)) +
  geom_bar(aes(totalpageviews, pagePath), stat = 'identity', fill = scales::muted('blue')))
```